# php oop not submitting to db

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I know a bit of php and starting to learn php oop and following a guide from alex at php academy how every when trying to insert into a db it doesn't seem to insert.

I have db detail set up like this

init.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'oop'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 2592000
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
    )
    );

    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
    ?>
```

this is my database class every thing seems to work fine untill i get to public function insert

db.php

```
<?php
class db {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_result,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') .         ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'),     config::get('mysql/password')); 
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    }
    public static  function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new db();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators =array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $vaule      = $where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field}         {$operator} ?";
                if (!$this->query($sql, array($vaule))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function delete() {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
        if(count($fields)){
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = '';
            $x = 1;

            foreach($fields as $field){
                $values .= '?';
                if($x < count($fields)){
                    $values .= ', ';
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`,`', $keys) . "`) VALUES     ({$values})";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function results(){
        return $this->_result;
    }

    public function first() {
        return $this->results()[0];
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

and this is what I am using to submit to db

index.php

```
    <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    $user = db::getInstance()->insert('users', array(
        'username' => 'pravaut',
        'passowrd' => 'test',
        'salt'     => 'salt'
));
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use singletons. Also, please pay attention to [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Especially the bit about PDO attributes. You are currently using an instance which will be emulating prepared statements .. thus negating all security benefits.

Comment: ok cool will look over that tut and see what i can but atm i just learning a bit so none of it will be hosted on the web just a local server but as for code above any idea?

Comment: probably because th values that you are trying to store are string .. that's all the hint you get

Comment: hmmm ok well thanks any way for info